# What does the "§" key do in insert mode?

Tags: insert-mode

I stumbled into a weird behavior when using vim and it has been month of me just enduring it.

When in insert mode, when I type on the "§" key my cursor jumps into my file.\

```
:h §
```

doesn't give anything, any online search led to nothing.

After some experimenting, this key seems to cut the character under the cursor and past it after the next apostrophe ( ' ) in the file.
Ex (with ^ denoting the cursor position, all in insert mode):

```
I can't  
  ^
```

becomes

```
I an'ct
     ^
```

Do you know where this behavior comes from? I would like to deactivate it as it often mess with my workflow, or remap it to some other action.

Thanks :)

By the way I'm on a French-Swiss keyboard and the key "§" is left of the "1" key.
I'm using vim version 8.2.3582 and my vimrc is quite small and standard I think:

```
set nocompatible
call plug#begin()
    Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
    Plug 'preservim/nerdtree'
    Plug 'preservim/nerdcommenter'
    Plug 'vim-scripts/AutoComplPop'
    Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
    Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
    Plug 'terryma/vim-multiple-cursors'
    Plug 'tpope/vim-surround'
    Plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
call plug#end()

set viminfo+=n~/.vim/viminfo
set noswapfile
set number relativenumber
set tabstop=4
set laststatus=2
set clipboard+=unnamedplus
set nrformats+=alpha
colorscheme atom-dark-256
let g:lightline = {'colorscheme' : 'one',}
" Autocomplete pop menu
set completeopt=menuone,longest
set shortmess+=c
" So that the autocomplete is case sensitive... I think
set noshowmode
set infercase

inoremap <expr> <Right> pumvisible() ? "<C-y>" : "<Right>"
inoremap <expr> <Tab> pumvisible() ? "<C-y>" : "<Tab>"
inoremap <expr> <CR> pumvisible() ? "<C-e><CR>" : "<CR>"

" remap splits navigation to just CTRL + hjkl
nnoremap <C-h> <C-w>h
nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j
nnoremap <C-k> <C-w>k
nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l

" remap just for gvim
inoremap <C-è> <Esc>
```

Edit:
After some testing it seems to be something related to the auto-pairs plugin.
This minimal vimrc gives me a minimum working example case:

```
call plug#begin()
    Plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
call plug#end()
```

Comment: If you enter Ctrl+V followed by `§` in Insert mode, what does Vim display? Does it show a sequence of characters, maybe some special characters? Can you reproduce the issue under `vim --clean`?

Comment: Your remap of `<C-è>` is a bit suspicious... If you remove it, does that fix the issue?

Comment: @filbranden ctrl+v gives me the ```§``` character and the issue doesn't seems to appear in ```vim --clean```. Also removing the ```<C-è>``` doesn't change the issue

Comment: After some digging (and trying to comment out plugins) I think the issue comes from the auto-pairs plugin

Comment: A snarky answer: that key does nothing by default. More realistically, I suspect the key is being translated somewhere, and possibly that translation is interacting with the plugin you mentioned.